# margin or <BR> for the best performance?

Tags: html, css, performance

Is it more efficient to add a `margin` to an HTML element or to insert a `<br/>` somewhere around it?

I wonder how both ways differ in the *type of page rendering* and, of course, how they *differ in speed.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a `margin` to an element, makes it much more efficient to work with. Just call the **class** or **element**, which will automatically add the margin.

A **line-break** might be forgotten now and then.

As for the speed: No experience in performance, but as you don't have to wait for the css, a line-break might be some nano seconds faster...

But then again, if you are using multiple elements which need some whitespace below adding a margin to it might be better, as your amount of code-lines will reduce (less kB).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do. If you are working with an element that is a part of a layout, then you MUST use margins/paddings. You can use `<br />` to make a little correction inside the text for example, but my way is to create a CSS class for `<p>` or other elements like that and simply use it. You can make a classes even for `<span>` elements to show it in some proper way. This is how I deal with this kind of issues. I think that using a lot of `<br />` isn't smart.
And what others say, `margin` gives you more control.